# Gap between matplotlib axis and inset_axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add an `inset_axis` which alings with the surrounding axis. Therefore, I set the first value of the `bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.5)` argument to zero. However, there is always a very small gap between their y-axes, see image:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 7))

background_geometry = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle(
    xy=(0, 0),
    width=5,
    height=7,
    linewidth=0,
    fill=True,
    color="yellow",
)
ax.add_patch(background_geometry)

inset_axes = inset_axes(
    ax, width=1, height=1, bbox_transform=ax.transData, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.55), loc=3
)

plt.show()
```

I know I can set it to a small negative value to adjust for this, but I would like to understand where this is coming from and how to properly solve the problem.
I also tried various idea including tight-layouts and margins, but none of the worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [inset_axes locator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes.html#mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.inset_axes) you use has a `borderpad` parameter which is by default 0.5, equivalent to a padding of 5 points. Just set it to zero to align both axes objects:

```
....    
in_ax = inset_axes(
    ax, width=1, height=1, bbox_transform=ax.transAxes, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.55), loc=3, 
    borderpad=0
)
....
```

Output:

[image]

You should also not overwrite the matplotlib `inset_axes` method with your new axis object in case you want to create a second inset.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is the solution!